# (Rails) How to display child records (one-to-many) in their parent's form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a "category" table that contains different kind of "product", so I create this in the category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

And this in product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categories
end
```

I would like to know how can I get the :categories from the product in the products/new.html.erb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Simplified code

I recommend that you use [Formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) which will do it [automatically for you](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1). If you want to do it rails without Formtastic, solution is:

Assuming you are using partial for `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`, the code will go into `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.label :category_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name%>
```

Comment: You need to make sure that `Product` model has `category_id` field and `products` table has the `category_id` column as well. You can run the following command in a new project to see the code.
`script/generate scaffold Product name:string category_id:integer`

Comment: I see, I added the productId in there, it works, thx u. But it shows the actual category_id instead of the category_name. 

Here is my code:
<% semantic_form_for @category do |f| %>  
<%= f.input :category, :include_blank => false %>  
 <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>

Comment: one more follow up, after I use this, the validate become crazy, I have several validate in my product.rb, after I input some data, it will treat me no input at all. what happen? I am using ruby script/generate migration add_category_id_to_product category_id:integer 

to add the category_id.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Also if it's require code, then you may want to post a new question where it's easy to provide you code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these Railscasts about complex (nested) forms and formtastic:

- [Complex forms (part 1)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) (at least check this)
- [Formtastic (part 1)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1)
- [Formtatic (part 2)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2)