# One to many relationship in ROR using Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, formtastic

following up with this topic:
[(Rails) How to display child records (one-to-many) in their parent's form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992094/one-to-many-relationship-in-ror)

I am creating a category that may have many products. So, I use the Formtastic as user Chandra Patni suggested. But I find there is a problem when I added attr_accessible to the product.rb.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :price
  validates_numericality_of :price
  validates_uniqueness_of :title

  attr_accessible :category_id, :name
  belongs_to :category

end
```

and this is the category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :products
end
```

After I added the       attr_accessible :category_id, :name , the validation gets crazy, no matter I type, it treats me as null in the text value. But after I remove the  attr_accessible :category_id, :name all stuff works.

One more thing, in the products/new.html.erb , I created this to input the product information,

```
<% semantic_form_for @product do |f| %>  
  <% f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :title %>  
    <%= f.input :price %>  
    <%= f.input :photoPath %>  
    <%= f.input :category %>  
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>
```

But I find that it return the :category id instead of the category name. What should I do?
Thx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add other attributes to `attr_accessible` for rails to perform mass assignment.

```
attr_accessible :category_id, :name, :title, :price, :photoPath
```

Rails will only do mass assignment for attributes specified in `attr_accessible` (white list) if you have one. It is necessary from security point of view. Rails also provides a way to blacklist mass assignments via `attr_protected` method.

You should see a drop down for category if you have `name` attribute in your `Category` model. See [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1) and [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2).

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  attr_accessible :name    
end
```

Comment: the web site only have     <%= f.input :category, :include_blank => false %>  

than they can return the category name, but I can't do so, I only get the Object id.

Comment: Do you have name attribute for category?